# Magento1 PLP and PDP Quires

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to print all queries on plp and pdp page in my magento1 how i can achieved this.

Comment: Please use Mysql Profiller as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql#answer-82757

Comment: i just want plp and pdp